# TIFF image in Python

Tags: python, tiff

I tried the following codes from [Working with TIFFs (import, export) in Python using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569553/working-with-tiffs-import-export-in-python-using-numpy)  :

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('Park_Falls.tif')
im.show()
```

**AND**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = plt.imread('Park_Falls.tif')
print im
```

But both didnt work for me.

```
IOError: cannot identify image file <open file 'Park_Falls.tif', mode 'rb' at 0x0000000022FB71E0>
```

Why? Is it because the TIFF image is too large (292 MB after unzipping) in size?

Image taken from [here](http://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/dsviewer.pl?ds_id=993) (Park_Falls.zip)

Comment: Have you tried using other (smaller) TIFF files?

Comment: Yes,with smaller TIFFs the code runs fine. Could the problem be related to the size of the file?

Comment: You could probably try that by converting a sufficiently large JPEG (or any other non-tif format) into a TIF using whatever tools you have available.

Comment: it's saying it can't recognize it as a TIFF file... it could have been too big, but i'd expect an 'out of memory' error or something like that instead. can you open it in other programs (e.g. photoshop, windows image viewer)? (looks like you have to have access to see the actual files...) from this page: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html it looks there are some types of compressed TIFF files it doesn't support, but if you install the module libtiff it can... maybe look into that?

Comment: @Corley I could view the image in Global Mapper(sorry but I don't remember from where I came to know about this GIS), not in Windows Image Viewer or PS. Also, I could only read the data(the array values) using gdal only.

Comment: try installing libtiff and see if it helps then, maybe... if PS can't open it, then it's a 'weird' tiff file, and you might need some help.

Comment: Park_falls*.tif is an uncompressed float32 RGB image. [GDAL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) and [tifffile.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html) are able to read the file.