# Successfully installed libtiff but while importing getting error

Tags: python-2.7, gdal, libtiff

I installed libtiff successfully in python 2.7 using "pip install libtiff". It successfully installed the libtiff-0.4.0 package.
But when I am importing the package using "import libtiff".I get an error which is:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/Python/p1.py", line 1, in <module>
     import libtiff
    File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\libtiff\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
      from .libtiff_ctypes import libtiff, TIFF, TIFF3D
        File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\libtiff\libtiff_ctypes.py", line 41,         in <module>
    raise ImportError('Failed to find TIFF library. Make sure that libtiff is    installed and its location is listed in PATH|LD_LIBRARY_PATH|..')
ImportError: Failed to find TIFF library. Make sure that libtiff is installed and its location is listed in PATH|LD_LIBRARY_PATH|..
```

Kindly Clarify.

Comment: HI @Shubham_geo,  I have seen many such posts around and it is said to be an issue of missing dll file. One thing you can do is, download `libtiff` binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ location and download appropriate .whl file and install it with using pip. And then you won't get such error.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!!!! You saved my day,it worked.

Comment: Anyone got a non-Windows solution? :\

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64403525/2104010), answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65776297/2104010)

Answer (score 1):

I got `libtiff` to work with the following steps:

- [install Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0](http://aka.ms/vcpython27)
- [install GnuWin32 TIFF](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/tiff.php)
- `pip install libtiff`

Then, in my script I just used the `os` library to add the necessary folder to my path:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "C:\\Program Files\\GnuWin32\\bin"
```

(Of course you can edit your path variable manually as well.)

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem, but when I install the packge offline I worked well.

you should download libtiff at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ where you search

libtiff in the web, then you can obtain it.

last, you can pip install that in its path.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75732689/5609823) (and in the comments), the solution is to install `pylibtiff` (and NOT libtiff):

```
pip install pylibtiff
```