# Python cannot find LibTIFF library, even though LibTIFF is already installed

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, tiff, libtiff

I need LibTIFF in order to compile TIFF images in PIL (as mentioned [here](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_tiff-pil.html) in the documentation).

I started with a simple `pip install LibTIFF`. After that installed successfully I tried running my code, which includes `import LibTIFF` - but got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tile_fetch_4.py", line 14, in <module>
    from libtiff import tiff
  File "C:\Users\i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\libtiff\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .libtiff_ctypes import libtiff, TIFF, TIFF3D
  File "C:\Users\i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\libtiff\libtiff_ctypes.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Failed to find TIFF library. Make sure that libtiff '
ImportError: Failed to find TIFF library. Make sure that libtiff is installed and its location is listed in PATH|LD_LIBRARY_PATH|..
```

Yet, when running `pip instal libtiff`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: libtiff in c:\users\i\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (0.4.2)
```

Why doesn't it recognize LibTIFF?

Comment: Probably unrelated but do you have numpy installed via pip? (per https://github.com/pearu/pylibtiff/issues/122)

Comment: The library [looks](https://github.com/pearu/pylibtiff/blob/51d6f2a41db654254397df1de6f9193e7317bce5/libtiff/libtiff_ctypes.py#L25) for `libtiff3.dll` in PATH.

Comment: Yep! Latest version of Numpy is installed.

Comment: @phd I would assume installing via pip would take care of that issue. How would I go about manually adding the dll to path (and where would I source it from)?

Comment: `PyLibTIFF` is not linked with `libtiff3.dll`. Instead it loads it using [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). For `libtiff3.dll` I think you need to download [the sources](https://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/) and [build](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/build.html#PC).

Comment: I have libtiff3.dll from the GnuWin32 TIFF file referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47188105/11181697). I then added the folder manually to both my user and system paths, but no go - still get the error.

Comment: The file is being looked up in [this exact place](https://github.com/pearu/pylibtiff/blob/51d6f2a41db654254397df1de6f9193e7317bce5/libtiff/libtiff_ctypes.py#L32).

Comment: I see - it is in program files (x64) instead of regular program files, that is likely the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go this site [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pylibtiff](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pylibtiff) and download precompiled whl file and do pip install pylibtiff‑0.4.2‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: ...if you're on Windows with an AMD64 chip.  ;-)