# How to open TIFF using PIL on Windows?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I'm trying to open a 12-band tiff (it stores 1 temperature image for each month of the year) using this code:

```
>>> from PIL import Image

>>> im = Image.open('a_image.tif')
```

I'm basing my procedure on this post: [Working with TIFFs (import, export) in Python using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569553/working-with-tiffs-import-export-in-python-using-numpy)

However, i get the error: `IOError: cannot identify image file`.  I've checked my path and file names.  What might be causing the problem? Is it a Windows OS issue or a multiband tiff issue?

Comment: Can you share your TIFF please? It's rather hard to guess what the problem could be without seeing the image.

Comment: @Mark Setchell Thanks!  https://www.dropbox.com/s/jf4e58o81ugv0kq/tmax_12km.tif?dl=0

Comment: PIL is not a good choice for handling GeoTIFF files. Try [GDAL](https://www.gdal.org/) or [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead. [Tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) can also read such TIFF files (LZW compressed floating point grayscale images with many extrasamples).

Comment: @cgohlke Thanks!  I was successful with GDAL opening and converting tiffs to numpy.