# Reading in an image with PIL

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read an image using PIL (I think it needs to be PIL because I am working with a filehandle and OpenCV was throwing an error when I tried using it to read in the image).

I would like to read in the image like so;

```
pil_image = Image.open('sample_image.tif').convert('RGB') # it is in tiff format

# and convert to numpy array
img = np.asarray(pil_image)

plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

However, whenever I try to convert the image and plot it, I get a blank result (as shown above). I need the NumPy array to be a uint8 for preprocessing reasons. But every method I use to convert the original image from PIL to a NumPy array with dtype=uint8 (the other method I tried is this..

```
pil_image = Image.open('Sample_image.tif')

img = np.array(pil_image) / 255
img = img.astype(np.uint8)
```

), I either get a blank screen or undesired results. Finally, I tried following some suggestions from here [Convert image from PIL to openCV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134892/convert-image-from-pil-to-opencv-format), and I get no luck. Any suggestions on how to solve this would be really helpful cheers.

Comment: Can you make it work with any other TIFF image? With any other *image*?

Comment: Hey, Check the Third comment on [How to open TIFF using PIL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815303/how-to-open-tiff-using-pil-on-windows)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah I experienced the same problems with other images of the same format (I'm working with multiple tif files)

Comment: Are you able to load and verify the contents of the .tif files in any other way?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yeah the first line works without applying the convert method. I found a workaround to the problem though but thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The easiest way to get a proper answer is to click [edit] and share your TIFF.

Answer (score 0):

*I can't put code all this code in comment, so if it doesn't answer/help you, I'll delete it.*

I ran the test below with the sample tiff (*1MB*) which you can find here:

https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-images-download/sample-tiff-download/

Put the sample in your content directory then try the code below:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gdal

img = mpimg.imread('sample.tiff') #change to your directory path

tif = gdal.Open('sample.tiff') #change to your directory path
tifArray = tif.ReadAsArray()
band1 = tif.GetRasterBand(1)
band1Array = band1.ReadAsArray()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,12))
for a in fig.get_axes():
  a.axis('off')

ax1.imshow(img)
ax2.imshow(band1Array)
```

The result should be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I'm just not keen on using Gdal because I'm already using three other image processing libraries and downloading gdal/osgeo is a real pain. I found a workaround but thanks anyway again.

Comment: You already use matplotlib, would you at least try the example with "mpimg" from matplotlib? Like this you could open AND plot with 1 module.