# Image that opens in matlab but not python

Tags: python, image, matlab, tiff

I have a multilayer `.tiff` image that I can open in matlab with either `imfinfo` or `imread`.  The results look as I expect.

However, I can't open the image in python: `PIL.Image.open` fails with `UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file`, and `exifreader` gives nonsense for the image tags.

I assume there's some part of the `tiff` standard that the python packages are checking and matlab is not, but I don't know how to debug further.  What are the first steps to take to figure out how the image is corrupted?

Comment: Can you open it in other applications, like a paint or image processing program?  Also, check this answer; there is an issue opening some TIFF files, it appears: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569553/working-with-tiffs-import-export-in-python-using-numpy ; pytiff might be the ticket.

Comment: I instead would suggest ussing libtiff as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44915514/1485872 . Likely you have a higher than 8 bit depth image. Libtiff is the standard to handle proper tiff data

Comment: “I assume there's some part of the TIFF standard...” A TIFF file can contain a lot of different image types and in a lot of different formats. Every reader in the world only reads a subset of possible standard-compliant TIFF files (by necessity, it’s impossible to support it all).

Comment: Could be a [BigTIFF](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/bigtiff.html) file, which is not supported by Pillow.

Comment: @cgohlke You got it!  Thanks a lot!  If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.